# What was the chronologically first derivation PV=nRT?

Tags: thermodynamics, steam-engines

Wikipedia describes the Ideal Gas Law as coming from a combination of Boyle's Law, Charles' Law, Avogadro's Law, and Gay-Lussac's Law. It gives several derivations, both empirical and theoretical, from kinetic theory and from statistical mechanics.

However, the article does not have any historical perspective. What I want to know is:

- Who was it that first combined these different laws into the familiar PV=nRT, and when?
- What derivation technique did he or she use at the time?
- Was it called the "Ideal Gas Law" at the time, or was that a later label?
- What was the state of knowledge of gas theory at the time? Were there competing theories that were taken seriously (e.g. non-atomic), or was the scientific community fairly unified around the kinetic theory?
- Was it considered a fatal problem that the ideal gas law didn't accurately describe real gases, or were people happy with the approximation? By "fatal problem", I mean, did people think there had to be a radical re-think of gas theory, or did they think the inaccuracies could be accommodated by small tweaks to the existing gas theory?
- What did people think were the reasons for why it isn't quite right for real gases? Obviously nowadays we know why, but what were the different hypotheses at the time?
- Did the unification have practical consequences in industry and engineering (e.g. steam engines), or were engineers already using the separate gas laws to the same effect? Or were engineers still using "rules of thumb" and not applying the cutting-edge theory just yet?

Comment: Too many questions. Even the cited Wikipedia article states that the unified law was derived by Clapeyron in 1834, from Carnot-like thermodynamic considerations with explicit simplifying assumptions made. It was clear why it applies only at low pressures. Kinetic theory of gases did not exist at the time to compete with or radically rethink, it was developed only in the second half of 19th century by Maxwell, Boltzmann, Gibbs, etc., and was only fully accepted in the early 20th. But van der Waals derived his refined equation based on it, to account for phase transitions, already in 1873.

Comment: Clapeyron's derivation and context are discussed in detail in [Saslow's History of Thermodynamics](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7516509/#sec7-entropy-22-00077). See also [van der Waals's Nobel lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/waals-lecture.pdf) for a first hand account of how he came to refining the gas law.

Comment: Welcome to HSMSE. We do not encourage to write too many question in a single post. Please consider editing your question to ask a single question.